# Binding the dynamic ComboBox collection

Tags: c#, wpf

Dynamic elements are added to the table. They are collected from the binding collection. When I choose another item in ComboBox, I would like other values associated with the new item to change.

How to bind SelectedIndex to a collection containing these indexes?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListConnectors}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SomeCollectionSelectedIndex}">
```

How to create a function to properly bind indices with items in the collection?

[image]

Comment: SelectedIndex is an integer property, you'll have a hard time binding a collection to it. I think we'll need more XAML (like, the actual table) to help properly.

Comment: I'm guessing selecteditem is the direction you want to head in. It gives you the object selected. Is what you want to change in that same datagrid row? Binding selecteditem and acting in the setter could be the way to do this but I'm guessing because I don't understand what you mean.